# GXWaitForCursor in Applinx API always fails by timeout

Tags: java, webmethods

I'm integrating a legacy application running on AIX with a new J2EE app using Applinx API.
After send some keys, I'm waiting the cursor jump to next field:

```
        wc = new GXWaitForCursor(new GXPosition(11, 22),new GXPosition(11, 33), 3000, 1000);

        client.sendKeys("[enter]1[enter]2[enter]3[enter]3[enter]");

        sr = new GXGetScreenRequest();
        sr.addWaitCondition(wc);

        screen = client.getScreen(sr);
```

While I can see (using Applinx Administrator) that the cursor has already reached that position, it wait until it fails by timeout.

Is there anyone who has faced this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to ask in the ApplinX official forum - http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/forums/show/169.page or contact ApplinX technical support - https://empower.softwareag.com.
A recording of an ApplinX session demonstrating the problem (trace file) and your ApplinX application (GXAR file) will be beneficial to understand the problem.

Thanks